# Last element of a list being pushed down after using float: right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create navigation menu in which last element is on the right side. When I use

```
float: right
```

That element is slightly lower that other elements of the navigation menu. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Here is my css:

```
nav ul{
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
nav ul li{
display: inline;
padding: 5px 1em;
}
nav ul li:last-child{
float: right;
}
```

And link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLqnm8r5/

Comment: The elements align if you set the first two to `float:left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements would align correctly if you added a `float:left;` to your first elements.
checkout [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLqnm8r5/2/)

Comment: @JCOC661 ah you beat me to it :P

Comment: Lol I didn't post it as an answer though, it might not satisfy the needs of the OP

Comment: It did satisfy my needs :P